# Add a owner to group using graph api

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add a owner to a Office 365 group which is failing with 400 error :

```
$headers = @{
Authorization = "Bearer $accesstoken"
"Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$addowner = @{
  "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{objectid of my user}/"
}

$createownerbody = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $addowner

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$groupid/owners/$ref" -Body $createownerbody -Method Post -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing
```

error :

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Write requests are only supported on contained entities",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a20e4ce8-fa4d-4aa1-93a7-deb960291d37",
      "date": "2020-03-29T08:26:45"
    }
  }
}
```

referring : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: To add an user as a owner to office 365 group, first we need to add the user as a member to the specified group and then we have to add the user as owner, did you do this way or trying to add owner directly?

Comment: I believe the issue is going to be with escaping PowerShell special characters. If you want to pass **$ref** literally, you need to backtick escape the $ --> **`$ref**